# Dumping configuration from a Sipura 8800

Tags: cisco, voip

Is there any way to retrieve the configuration from a Cisco Sipura 8800?

And no, I'm not talking about [nonsense like saving the HTML pages](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-9905). I'm talking about saving the proper .xml configurations so you can put those into revision control or put it onto your tftp server for provisioning.

On some devices (such as the PAP2T and some phones) you can [retrieve the configuration from a particular URL](http://forum.voxilla.com/cisco-linksys-sipura-support-forum/any-way-generate-xml-linksys-device-21853.html#post101057). But that doesn't work on the SPA8800.

Please tell me there's another magic URL to retrieve its configuration!

---

Things that don't work:

```
http://spa8800/admin.config.xml
http://spa8800/admin/spacfg.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `http://<spa_ip_address>/admin/config.xml` as mentioned in the above [link](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-9905)?

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for the 8800 but I guess you could give it a try.

I have an SPA3000, and I use this for backing up the config to an XML file:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160531155820/http://voiptuts.com/2011/10/how-to-backup-saveload-spa-3000_02.html

Comment: Ugh… a link to a dodgy Windows-only executable from a site that's not loading? We'll see…. I have my doubts though.

Comment: heh, it's been a long time since I've used it TBH, I didn't check to see if it was still there or not.  Still in the absence of anything else it might be worth a try.